# Make hyperlinks selectable

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you browse webpages using Firefox or Chrome, you can select text in a hyperlink, an element with `<a>` tag, by holding right alt key.

In my app, I want to achieve this using javascript, not by holding some button but by default. I will redirect to url if user doubleclicks, otherwise user will be able to select the content as if it's just a plain text.

First thing I tried is to replace all `<a>` elements with `<span>`elements and implement relevant events. This provides the functionality I wanted, but distorts the look considerably even tough I keep all attributes (class, id) same. It seems there are tag `<a>` specific css for the pages I'm dealing with.

Now what am trying is to achieve this by keeping tagname. My current code is as follows:

```
var linkElems = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = linkElems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    linkElems[i].ondblclick = function () {
           //redirect to url
        };

    linkElems[i].setAttribute("href", "#");
    linkElems[i].onclick = function () { return false; };       
}
```

After this code, links does not make page redirect to respective url, but when I try to select the text it just drags some box having the url in it. To prevent that, I wrote this line of code:

```
document.body.ondragstart = function(){return false;}
```

Now, I prevent the drag but still can't select the text. I wonder is there a way to fix this.

Comment: I think the first idea was the good one, then you just have to look into CSS what attributes are setted for <a> and set them on your span links too.

Comment: @rakwaht I didn't think it was a good idea, because I don't create those files and I don't want to modify them. Plus, sometimes there was libraries like bootstrap and you wouldn't want to change them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this.

I used data attribute and did not define `href` attribute.

You can find more information about `data-*` attribute on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

```js
$(function(){
    $(".aLink").dblclick(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("data-href");
    window.location.href = link;
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a data-href="https://example.com" class ="aLink">Link 1</a> <br><br>
<a data-href="https://example.com/something" class ="aLink">Likn 2</a>
```

Comment: But you don't have the pointer element anymore which is sort of disturbing the user ...

Comment: CSS property can be added `cursor: pointer`. Its just that if it is pointer user might have a perception that they can not select it.

Comment: Actually, I didn't have any trouble implementing double click and used a custom data-href attribute to keep url just like in your example. Problem is, I was not removing href attribute but setting it to "#". Thanks for pointing that out.